# how to return array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have this code..

```
var players = [{
    name: "Luka Modric",
    age: 33,
    debut: 2006,
    team: "Real Madrid",
    position: "Midfielder",
    country: "Croatian",
    url: "https://media.guim.co.uk/737d9bde5b3cf33b0230c887acfadf9e68c427bd/169_141_3371_2023/500.jpg",
    awards: [{
        name: "The Best FIFA Men's Player",
        year: 2016
      },
      {
        name: "Ballon",
        year: 2018
      },
      {
        name: "The Best FIFA Men's Player",
        year: 2018
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    name: "Cristiano Ronaldo",
    age: 33,
    debut: 2003,
    team: "Juventus",
    position: "Forward",
    country: "Portugal",
    url: "https://media.guim.co.uk/f53bba20898fef82548e3b8369d68b3c9b25b4c1/1_189_3919_2351/500.jpg",
    awards: [{
        name: "The Best FIFA Men's Player",
        year: 2017
      },
      {
        name: "European Golden Shoe",
        year: 2015
      },
      {
        name: "Ballon",
        year: 2018
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    name: "NGolo Kanté",
    age: 27,
    debut: 2007,
    team: "Chelsea",
    position: "Midfielder",
    country: "France",
    url: "https://media.guim.co.uk/9aeaf1767280c511ff5295a293e9bafe20f35d65/0_129_4105_2463/500.jpg",
    awards: [{
        name: "FIFA FIFPro World XI",
        year: 2018
      },
      {
        name: "French Player of the Year",
        year: 2017
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Lionel Messi",
    age: 31,
    debut: 2003,
    team: "Barcelona",
    position: "Forward",
    country: "Argentina",
    url: "https://media.guim.co.uk/b035e8f52c5b5612121fdcf8b54bf149be4f67e7/0_211_3846_2307/500.jpg",
    awards: [{
        name: "FIFA World Player of the Year",
        year: 2009
      },
      {
        name: "The Best FIFA Men's Player",
        year: 2019
      },
      {
        name: "European Golden Shoe",
        year: 2018
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

How to return array of objects whenever the debut year equal to 2003?

Comment: share your code implementation. what you tried to solve this question.

Comment: Please format your code properly. Please add also expected output to make the question as clear as possible. Please note that SO is not for this kind of questions (no code -> I want solution). Oh, and to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) your values, use `players.filter(p=>p.debut===2003)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [JS Array Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), specifically [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). This code should do what you need:

```
var playersWhoDebutedIn2003 = players.filter(player => { return player.debut === 2003;});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
players.filter(({debut}) => debut===2003);
```

Here for testing:

```js
var players = [{ name: "Luka Modric", age: 33, debut: 2006, team: "Real Madrid", position: "Midfielder", country: "Croatian", url: "https://media.guim.co.uk/737d9bde5b3cf33b0230c887acfadf9e68c427bd/169_141_3371_2023/500.jpg", awards: [{ name: "The Best FIFA Men's Player", year: 2016 }, { name: "Ballon", year: 2018 }, { name: "The Best FIFA Men's Player", year: 2018 } ] },

               { name: "Cristiano Ronaldo", age: 33, debut: 2003, team: "Juventus", position: "Forward", country: "Portugal", url: "https://media.guim.co.uk/f53bba20898fef82548e3b8369d68b3c9b25b4c1/1_189_3919_2351/500.jpg", awards: [{ name: "The Best FIFA Men's Player", year: 2017 }, { name: "European Golden Shoe", year: 2015 }, { name: "Ballon", year: 2018 } ] },

               { name: "NGolo Kanté", age: 27, debut: 2007, team: "Chelsea", position: "Midfielder", country: "France", url: "https://media.guim.co.uk/9aeaf1767280c511ff5295a293e9bafe20f35d65/0_129_4105_2463/500.jpg", awards: [{ name: "FIFA FIFPro World XI", year: 2018 }, { name: "French Player of the Year", year: 2017 } ] }, { name: "Lionel Messi", age: 31, debut: 2003, team: "Barcelona", position: "Forward", country: "Argentina", url: "https://media.guim.co.uk/b035e8f52c5b5612121fdcf8b54bf149be4f67e7/0_211_3846_2307/500.jpg", awards: [{ name: "FIFA World Player of the Year", year: 2009 }, { name: "The Best FIFA Men's Player", year: 2019 }, { name: "European Golden Shoe", year: 2018 } ] }, ];
               
let result = players.filter(({debut}) => debut===2003);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: suppose if we want to extract the players details who are debuted in year 2005 and 2006? how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter function of array like this

```
players.filter(player => player.debut === 2003)
```

See below output.

```js
var players = [{
    name: "Luka Modric",
    age: 33,
    debut: 2006,
    team: "Real Madrid",
    position: "Midfielder",
    country: "Croatian",
    url: "https://media.guim.co.uk/737d9bde5b3cf33b0230c887acfadf9e68c427bd/169_141_3371_2023/500.jpg",
    awards: [{
        name: "The Best FIFA Men's Player",
        year: 2016
      },
      {
        name: "Ballon",
        year: 2018
      },
      {
        name: "The Best FIFA Men's Player",
        year: 2018
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    name: "Cristiano Ronaldo",
    age: 33,
    debut: 2003,
    team: "Juventus",
    position: "Forward",
    country: "Portugal",
    url: "https://media.guim.co.uk/f53bba20898fef82548e3b8369d68b3c9b25b4c1/1_189_3919_2351/500.jpg",
    awards: [{
        name: "The Best FIFA Men's Player",
        year: 2017
      },
      {
        name: "European Golden Shoe",
        year: 2015
      },
      {
        name: "Ballon",
        year: 2018
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    name: "NGolo Kanté",
    age: 27,
    debut: 2007,
    team: "Chelsea",
    position: "Midfielder",
    country: "France",
    url: "https://media.guim.co.uk/9aeaf1767280c511ff5295a293e9bafe20f35d65/0_129_4105_2463/500.jpg",
    awards: [{
        name: "FIFA FIFPro World XI",
        year: 2018
      },
      {
        name: "French Player of the Year",
        year: 2017
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Lionel Messi",
    age: 31,
    debut: 2003,
    team: "Barcelona",
    position: "Forward",
    country: "Argentina",
    url: "https://media.guim.co.uk/b035e8f52c5b5612121fdcf8b54bf149be4f67e7/0_211_3846_2307/500.jpg",
    awards: [{
        name: "FIFA World Player of the Year",
        year: 2009
      },
      {
        name: "The Best FIFA Men's Player",
        year: 2019
      },
      {
        name: "European Golden Shoe",
        year: 2018
      }
    ]
  },
];

var output = players.filter(player => player.debut === 2003);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: suppose if we want to extract the players details who are debuted in year 2005 and 2006? how to do that ?

Comment: `players.filter(player => player.debut === 2005 || player.debut === 2006)` use this